Why does Docker Hub request returns a 409 status when I log in
I am trying to log into my Docker account through Docker Hub on VS Code, but I end up getting a 409: Conflict error when it tries to send a request to https://hub.docker.com/v2/users/login. It might be my credentials, but I can't redo the login sequence. How can I fix this? Also, can I just use docker without Docker Hub? I'm new to this, and I'm not sure where I'm going with it yet.
Things that might be tied into this that could help:

I'm getting an error saying Docker isn't installed. I have the Docker Desktop app open, and I can run Docker on my terminal (which proves it is installed)

This has been an issue I have been having for about a month now, and it is REALLY frustrating!
